# Assign value to Dynamic variable inside While Loop

Tags: c#

I'm doing an application that will read a file and parse all the script name that this file execute.
I want to be able to stuck each script name in different variable so once the program is done reading the first file he can go read the second file that would be stock in my first dynamic variable. Since i'm reading a file line by line when i find a script name to execute i display it in a richtextbox but how can i also add it to a dynamic variable.

Example
First file executed contains:

```
blablabla
@Exec=test.sqi
blablabla
@Exec=test2.sqi
```

At the end of my file reading i want to be able to have variable like those:
ScriptName1 = test.sqi
ScriptName2 = test2.sqi

```
 while ((Line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (Line.Contains(FirstString))
            {

                int Pos1 = Line.IndexOf(FirstString) + FirstString.Length;
                int Pos2 = Line.IndexOf(LastString);
                FinalString = Line.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1);
                FinalStringTrimed = FinalString.Trim('(',')');
                Extension = FinalStringTrimed.Substring(0,3);
                Extension = "." + Extension ;
                FileName = FinalStringTrimed.Substring(4, FinalStringTrimed.Length - 4);
                FullFileName = FileName + Extension;

                richTextBoxProcess.AppendText(FullFileName);
                richTextBoxProcess.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                MessageBox.Show(FullFileName);    

            }


            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

    }
```

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create simple array or better `List<string>` for that purpose like this:

```
List<string> Scripts = new List<string>();
Scripts.Add("firstScriptName");
Scripts.Add("secondScriptName");
Scripts.Add("thirdScripName");
```

and you can access it like `Scripts[0]` for `firsScriptName` or irritate through it with `foreach(string s in Scripts)` or do transform it to simple array like `string[] arrayScripts = Scripts.ToArray()`

Comment: thanks its working properly however i have another question maybe you guide me the second file i'm going throught is an HTML file and it seems like the  If Contains() method is not working for parsing this file when i try we another type of file like an SQL it work fine ..any idea why is that ?thanks

Comment: Seems like i need to use an HTML parser neverming i will read on that thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 1;
var scriptName = "ScriptName";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        while ((Line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var cols = Line.Split('=');

            if(cols.Length < 2) {
                continue;
            }

            var value = cols[1];
            dict[string.Format("{0}{1}", scriptName, counter)] = value;

            counter++;
        }

        foreach(var keyValue in dict) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value));
        }
```